# How to rename the image before it upload to s3 bucket?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to rename the image before it upload to s3 Bucket to avoid duplication of image(s3 will replace new image with old one if any identical file going to upload) in javaScript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  A FileUpload object:
  <input type="file" id="upload" name="filename">

  <p>Click the buttons below to display and/or change the value of the name attribute of the file button above.</p>

  <button onclick="display()">Display name</button>
  <button onclick="change()">Change name</button>

  <script>
    function display() {
      var fullPath = document.getElementById('upload').value;
      if (fullPath) {
        var startIndex = (fullPath.indexOf('\\') >= 0 ? fullPath.lastIndexOf('\\') : fullPath.lastIndexOf('/'));
        var filename = fullPath.substring(startIndex);
        if (filename.indexOf('\\') === 0 || filename.indexOf('/') === 0) {
          filename = "hello" + filename.substring(1);

        }
        alert(filename);
      }

    }

    function change() {
      var x = document.getElementById("myFile").name = "newFileName";
      alert("The name was changed to: " + x);
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

In the above code it just geting the file name and trying to append something(what we want like "random number").  **but i want to upload image with new name to s3 bucket**

Comment: But where is the S3Client?

Comment: S3 upload  is implemented in back end. i got one  post method i have to use that with file path

Comment: I'll ditto @Novice - where is your S3Client code? You should - at least - have code that uploads with the *same* name to start off with.

Comment: Consider using a guid for the object name and store the actual filename in metadata, or in a separate key/value store that refers back to the object's key.

Comment: code snippet please @jarmod

Comment: You haven't shown us any server-side code, or even indicated which language you're writing in. Here's a high-level description of one way to do what you want: the client requests an upload URL from your server, your server generates a guid for the uploaded object name and then returns a pre-signed upload URL for that object to the client, then the client uploads to that pre-signed URL, then the client tells the server that it's done. Creating a guid/uuid is simple and a quick web search will help you.